Getting error while running Robot framework script using Browser library
I have recently installed nodejs, robotframework-browser and python on my system. I have test cases running fine in jenkins but when i am running in my local i am getting an error:

ERROR ] Calling method '_start_suite' of listener 'Browser' failed: Could not connect to the playwright process at port 62017.
[ ERROR ] Calling method '_start_test' of listener 'Browser' failed: Could not connect to the playwright
process at port 62017.
[ ERROR ] Calling method '_en

I have tried uninstalling robotframework and nodejs and installing it again but this error is still coming up.

Please share a [mcve].

I struggle on the same thing, but Have you executed rfbrowser init ?
